# MailChimp API Issue

Tags: php, api, mailchimp

I want to add email to mailchimp subscriber.code is running fine but it sends an email to user for subscription confirmation.how do i add user without his confirmation?.
here is my code

```
<?php

include('Mailchimp.php');

$api_key = "mykey"; 
$list_id = "d12a719916";


$mailChimp = new Mailchimp($api_key);


$result=$mailChimp->call("lists/subscribe", array(
"id"=>"d12a719916",
"email"=>array("email"=>"testuser@somedomain.com"),
"update_existing"=>true,
"send_welcome"=>false,
));
var_dump($result);

?>
```

result of this code is

```
array(3) { ["email"]=> string(23) "testuser@somedomain.com" ["euid"]=> string(10) "4a702d4cbb" ["leid"]=> string(8) "47980385" }
```

where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `double_optin` to `false` in your call.

Example:

```
$result=$mailChimp->call("lists/subscribe", array(
"id"=>"d12a719916",
"email"=>array("email"=>"testuser@somedomain.com"),
"double_optin"=>false,
"update_existing"=>true,
"send_welcome"=>false,
));
```

More information [here](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php).

Comment: and how to add first name and lastname in this call ?

Comment: @adeelpervaiz It's all in the documentation :). You can add the firstname and lastname by setting `merge_vars` to an array containing the firstname and lastname tags as key and the firstname and lastname as value for these keys.

Please accept my answer if it answered your question. Thanks!